# Restrict content length of div, within the innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div having various html tags and their inner text within the inner html. I want to restrict the length of content of this div, excluding the tags. I need to remove the last character from the last tag if the content exceeds a limit.
Example.

```
<div class="main-div">
  <div>This is a blog post. bla bla bla</div>
  <div>
    <ol>
      <li>text1</li>
      <li>text2</li>
    </ol>
    <div>text continues here.</div>
  </div>
  <div>what is this here.</div>
  <div>this is the last tag. this is the last character .</div>
</div>
```

In the above example. In the main-div, the last character in the last child node is a '.', and this needs to be removed.

Comment: Examples would be useful

Comment: Please show people what you have tried to do and did not work, possibly with some code examples, so that they can better understand your problem and try to help

Comment: I have added an example to clarify my question.

Comment: *Please show people what you have tried to do and did not work.* StackOverflow is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a glance.

please, show us your JS code to know how to fit it in.

```
  var list = document.querySelector(".main-div").lastElementChild;
  list.innerHTML = list.innerHTML.substr(0, list.innerHTML.length-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple [CSS text-overflow Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp) can be used:

```
div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/37Lu458m/)